# InstantiationException in persistent entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have a problem when I get an object from hibernate. The stacktrace is:

```
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate entity: main.java.com.gwt.app.server.User
at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:114)
at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:123)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.instantiate(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:603)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3911)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1422)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1411)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1446)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1355)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:611)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3293)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1005)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:998)
at main.java.com.gwt.app.server.User.loadUser(User.java:50)
at main.java.com.gwt.app.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:22)
at main.java.com.gwt.app.client.Main.main(Main.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:111)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:900)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:455)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at main.java.com.gwt.app.server.User.<init>(User.java:33)
... 30 more
```

My User.hbm.xml file is:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="main.java.com.gwt.app.server"> 
<class name="User" table="USR">
    <id column="login" name="login" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property column="password" name="password" type="java.lang.String"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and User class:

```
package main.java.com.gwt.app.server;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

public class User {
private String login;
private String password;
private SessionFactory sesionFactory;
private Session sesion;

public void setSesionFactory(SessionFactory sesionFactory){
    this.sesionFactory = sesionFactory;
    this.sesion = this.sesionFactory.openSession();
}

public User(String user, String pass) {
    ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("resources/spring.xml");
    XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(res);
    this.sesionFactory = (SessionFactory)factory.getBean("sessionFactory");
    this.sesion = this.sesionFactory.openSession();
    this.login = user;
    this.password = pass;
}
public User() {
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}
public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String loadUser(String log){
    return ((User)sesion.get(User.class, log)).getLogin();
}
}
```

And I reference in spring file to mapping file:

```
<property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>
                User.hbm.xml
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

The libraries that I use:

```
hibernate3.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.1.0.M1.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
```

So, I do not know why is the reason which returns the error. I need help

Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the exception stacktrace, you'll see a Caused by: NoClassDefFoundError. This is the original cause of the error that should be solved. I suspect Andreas_D is right.

Comment: How are your libraries managed? And no offense but why are you using M1 release of a framework you are not that familiar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't have default public constructor in your class or maybe (I don't use .hbm files rather annotations) class name in User.hbm.xml class name should be fully qualified?

Please, post your User class code.

Comment: @Jose Hdez: Which one was the answer?

Comment: I think the constructor. I had a similar issue where I needed to have a no-arg constructor for Hibernate instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

A package named `main.java.com.gwt.app.server`? I'm pretty sure, that the package name really should be `com.gwt.app.server` and the source directory is `./main/java`.

Change the package declaration in `User` to

```
package com.gwt.app.sever;
```

and set the new package name in your `User.hbm.xml` file. Good chance that it solves the issue already.

---

This is the real problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
```

The `FatalBeanException` class is not on the classpath. It should be in one of springframeworks libraries so you should (1) check which library contains this class and (2) double check if this library is on the classpath at runtime.

Comment: That's a pretty non-standard choice for a package name. In the most common build setups (e.g., Maven), your java code is stored in the src/main/java directory, but your package names will not include those, as the build system will assume src/main/java is the source directory.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you're missing is that you need to have the full path to your mapping files, including the directories for your packages:

```
<property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
        <value>
            main/java/com/gwt/app/server/User.hbm.xml
        </value>
    </list>
</property>
```